# Do comments on deleted posts count towards the Just Jesting and Think! hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

I'm wondering if comments on deleted posts will count towards the Just Jesting and Think! hats. For instance, I commented on 10 different questions, all of which got an upvote. However, one of the question gets deleted by the OP.

Will I still earn the Just Jesting hat?

---

The description for both hats are as follows:

**Just Jesting**

> post 10 comments that each earn an upvote

**Think!**

> for 6 separate questions or answers, post gets edited by owner after you comment on it

Comment: Interesting question. I've been reviewing Low Quality Posts a lot since Winter Bash started to earn the Just Jesting hat for "this does not answer the question etc" comments. I haven't earned the hat yet, but I don't know if it's because those comments don't count (because the answer is deleted) or if it's just because they haven't been upvoted yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing in the logic of those two hats that looks at the deletion state of the parent post, only the deletion state of the comment itself. So yes, eligible comments that happen to be on a deleted post will still be considered.

Comment: So if comment is deleted, it won't be counted?